# Computing a moving average when data points arrive one at a time

Tags: smoothing

I am sure there's a cool python/numpy/pandas way to do this.

I am receiving one data point at a time. I would like to compute something like a moving average over the last n observations, even better with exponential smoothing.

I could have a circular buffer where I drop the oldest observation, add the newest, and compute the smoothing on that. I'm looking for a more elegant approach.

Comment: The whole point to exponential smoothing is that it can be performed online as an update of the previous value.  See the first paragraph of the Wikipedia article at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_smoothing.

Comment: @whuber: do you want to post your comment(s) as an answer? [Better to have a short answer than no answer at all.](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5326/1352) Anyone who has a better answer can post it.